# How to calculate the values of one column taking into account the values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, exists

I need a query that allows me to calculate the values of a column taking into account the values in another table, more precisely, I need to calculate if the users are still active(if a user has all expired roles, then he is inactive), taking into account the departure_date the second table

**user_role** table

| id_user | id_role | departure_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-05-05 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-06-18 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-04-12 |

**user** table

| id_user | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | George |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Alex |

I want to return this table, where 1 is active and 0 is inactive:

**user** table

| id_user | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | 1 |
| 2 | John | 0 |
| 3 | Alex | 0 |

At this point, I've made a query, which returns all my inactive users and active users that have  one or more assigned roles. I want to get all users including those who do not have an assigned role (like Alex, in my example)

```
SELECT user_management.user.*,
       if(count(CASE when current_date() > departure_date_organization 
                     then 1 END) = count(*),0,1) as status
FROM user_management.user, 
     user_organization_role 
WHERE user.id_user = user_management.user_organization_role.id_user 
GROUP BY user.id_user;
```

Using my query, I got this result, that not contain `Alex`:

| id_user | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | 1 |
| 2 | John | 0 |

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need joins and aggregation.
Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT u.*,
       EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 
         FROM user_management.user_organization_role r 
         WHERE r.id_user = u.id_user AND r.departure_date_organization > CURRENT_DATE
       ) status
FROM user_management.user u;
```